# Can I get total_pages using WillPaginate::Collection.create()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

Using .paginate on any model in Rails gives the total_pages parameter. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to get total_pages while using WillPaginate::Collection.create()?

Thanks                                                                                   Vishal

Answer (score 2):

The gem [sets](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/collection.rb#L117) the `total_pages` when the `total_entries` is set. You need to either pass the total entries to the create method OR assign it inside the block.

```
total_entires = ..
@entries = WillPaginate::Collection.create(1, 10, total_entires) do |pager|
  #..
end
```

**OR**

```
@entries = WillPaginate::Collection.create(1, 10) do |pager|
  #..
  pager.total_entries = # assign the count..
end
```